# Add column function fails on second run for a jQuery datatable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to add multiple columns to a DataTable one after the other.

Here is the code :

```
var theDT;
var counter = 0;

function getDataFromDT(dt){
    return dt.rows().data().toArray();
}

function getColumnsFromDT(dt){
    return dt.settings()[0].aoColumns;
}
function addColumn() {
    console.log(counter);
    addColumnToDataTable("#theDataTable","addedField"+counter,"addedTitle"+counter,[8,9]);
    counter += 1;
}

function addColumnToDataTable(datatableId,columnFieldName,columnTitle,columnValues) {

    var cols = [];
    var data = [];
    var dt;

    if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable(datatableId)) {
        if (datatableId == "#theDataTable") {
            dt = theDT;
        } else {
            alert("Trying to add column to unknow DataTable.");
            return;
        }
        cols = getColumnsFromDT(dt);
        data = getDataFromDT(dt);
        if (typeof dt != "undefined") {
            dt.destroy();
        }
        $(datatableId).empty();
    }

    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        data[i][columnFieldName] = columnValues[i];
    }
    cols.push(
        {
            "data":columnFieldName,
            "title":columnTitle
        }
    );

    dt = $(datatableId).DataTable({
        columns:cols,
        data: data
    }); 
}

$(function() {   

    $("#theButton").click(addColumn);


    theDT = $("#theDataTable").DataTable({
            table:"display nowrap",
            data:[{test:1,test2:2},{test:3,test2:4}],
            columns: [
                {
                    "data":"test",
                    "title":"test"
                },
                {
                    "data":"test2",
                    "title":"test2"
                }
        ],
            "dom":"t"
        });

});
```

Everything is in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2xvscuus/1/)

I can add one column without issue but when I click on the button again I get the dreaded `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.` error message.

I don't understand why it would work the first time and not the second.

All help welcome !

Answer (score 0):

The error throws because global variable 'theDt' keep the previous instance of the data table object. So you have to update the value of theDt variable with new data table object. I have updated your code on line no 51. 
Please check following code.

```
 var theDT;
var counter = 0;

function getDataFromDT(dt){
    return dt.rows().data().toArray();
}

function getColumnsFromDT(dt){
    return dt.settings()[0].aoColumns;
}



function addColumn() {
addColumnToDataTable("#theDataTable","addedField"+counter,"addedTitle"+counter,[8,9]);
counter += 1;
}

function addColumnToDataTable(datatableId,columnFieldName,columnTitle,columnValues) {

    var cols = [];
    var data = [];
    var dt;


    if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable(datatableId)) {
        if (datatableId == "#theDataTable") {
            dt = theDT;
        } else {
            alert("Trying to add column to unknow DataTable.");
            return;
        }
        cols = getColumnsFromDT(dt);
        data = getDataFromDT(dt);
        if (typeof dt != "undefined") {
            dt.destroy();
        }
        $(datatableId).empty();
    }

    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        data[i][columnFieldName] = columnValues[i];
    }
    cols.push(
        {
            "data":columnFieldName,
            "title":columnTitle
        }
    );

    theDT = $(datatableId).DataTable({
        columns:cols,
        data: data
    }); 
}

$(function() {   

$("#theButton").click(addColumn);


theDT = $("#theDataTable").DataTable({
        table:"display nowrap",
        data:[{test:1,test2:2},{test:3,test2:4}],
        columns: [
            {
                "data":"test",
                "title":"test"
            },
            {
                "data":"test2",
                "title":"test2"
            }
    ],
        "dom":"t"
    });

});
```

I also have updated your fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/2xvscuus/2/

Comment: OK got it thanks but the point is I want to select the datatable i'm doing the operation on in the beginning (that's the point of `if (datatableId == "#theDataTable") {
            dt = theDT;`. Any way to pass the object by reference to `dt` so anything I do on `dt` gets transmitted to `theDT` ?

Comment: You have to store theDt variable in an object for pass by reference. I have updated jsfiddle to demonstrate that. https://jsfiddle.net/2xvscuus/3/

Comment: OK maybe I wasn't clear. Let's assume I have several DT this function could apply to and I need to select only one of them ? (the criteria for selection being the name of the `datatableId`) So your `global` var would have several datatables in it and in 'getColumnsFromDT` you can't assume I know which one to extract from.